# Build object with different input, using super-class and sub-class style, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to model a object of air, the temperature of which can be given in 3 different ways:

1. if the value is known (assuming the temperature is a constant)
2. if a curve of the values with different time is known (using interpolation)
3. if the formula of the temperature vs time is known.

My code is below:

```
from script.interpolate import interp1d
from importlib import import_module

class Air1:
    # case 1: temperature, which is a constant value, is given in the input.
    def __init__(self, meta: dict):
        self.city = meta['city']
        self.temperature = meta['temperature']

class Air2(Air1):
    # case 2: a curve of temperature vs time is given in meta.
    # times is a list, temperatures is a list.
    # so self.get_temperature is an interpolated function.
    # To get a new temperature, I can use new_temp = self.get_temperature(new_time)
    def __init__(self, meta: dict):
        super().__init__(meta=meta)
        times = meta['times']
        temperatures = meta['temperatures']
        self.get_temperature = interp1d(times, temperatures)

class Air3(Air1):
    # case 3: the formula to calculate temperature from time is known.
    # this formula is implemented in a python file called file_of_fomurla.
    # so self.get_temperature is an imported function.
    # To get a new temperature, I can use new_temp = self.get_temperature(new_time)
    def __init__(self, meta: dict):
        super().__init__(meta=meta)
        file_of_formula = meta['file_of_formula']
        self.get_temperature = import_module(file_of_formula + '.my_function')
```

One thing I have noticed in my code is that `.temperature` should only be in `Air1`, since `Air2` and `Air3` both just have a function to calculate temperature value based on time. However, like in my code, `Air2` and `Air3` are sub classes of `Air1`, but their input `meta` will not have the key 'temperature'. So this is an error.

Do you have any better way to implement the physics behind into the model. Maybe using some abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you yourself have noted, the inheritance isn't benefiting you at all. Just write one class.

Passing `meta` as a `dict` is unidiomatic. Use `**kwargs` or parameters with defaults instead.

Consider [dropping the `get_…` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618176/1157100).

Also consider passing the formula as code (e.g. a lambda) rather than referencing a module by name.

```
from script.interpolate import interp1d
from importlib import import_module

class Air:
    def __init__(self, city, **kwargs):
        self.city = city
        self.temperature = (
            lambda time: kwargs['temperature'] if 'temperature' in kwargs else
            interp1d(kwargs['times'], kwargs['temperatures']) if 'times' in kwargs else            
            import_module(kwargs['file_of_formula'] + '.my_function') if 'file_of_formula' in kwargs else
            kwargs['formula']
        )
```

Comment: @MaartenFabré They are all meant to be callable, taking a `time` parameter.

Comment: thanks for your tips. There is a small issue, in `Air1`, `temperature` is a value, so it should not be a function with a `time` parameter. And by the way, could you give me an example when `kwarts['formula']` is used, assuming the formula is `temperature = 2 * time + 1`. Thanks again.

Comment: The object _must_ behave consistently, regardless of whether the temperature is constant or varying. A constant temperature is just a special case where it returns the same value no matter what the time is. So, it's a method that ignores its `time` parameter.

Comment: To instantiate an `Air` object with an _ad hoc_ formula: `gotham = Air('Gotham', formula=lambda t: 2 * t + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use define a private attribute `_temperature` to hold the temperature from `meta`, and set it to `None` if it is not defined, and define a `temperature` `property`:

```
class Air1:
    # case 1: temperature, which is a constant value, is given in the input.
    def __init__(self, meta: dict):
        self.city = meta['city']
        self._temperature = meta.get('temperature', None)

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        if self._temperature is None:
            raise NotImplementedError
        return self._temperature
```